# Create a counter variable in wp_options that increments when submit button is pressed

Tags: options

I'm a php beginner. I have an order form on my site (NB: the form is generated from a custom products plugin).
I want to create a reference code whenever a user submits, now I need help with creating a counter in wp_options whenever an order is made to use as the reference.

Answer (score 1):

SOLVED

```
if ( isset( $_POST['submit'] ) ) {
    $option_name = 'order_ref' ;
$counter = get_option( 'order_ref' );

//Limit the counter, based on the range of orders you will be getting per day
if ($counter <= 99 ) {
$counter = $counter + 1;
} else {
$counter = 1;
}

if ( get_option( $option_name ) !== false ) {
// The option already exists, so we just update it.
update_option( $option_name, $counter );

} else {
$deprecated = null;
$autoload = 'no';
add_option( $option_name, $counter, $deprecated, $autoload );
}
```

Comment: I think you wanted to use instead : 
$option_name = 'order_ref' ;
$counter = get_option( $option_name );